# process Result of a sms api

Tags: php, api, sms

I work with a sms api that very bad :-| .
when i sent arrays of numbers and message contents to it. the result is a string like this

```
 stdClass Object
([SendSMSResult] => stdClass Object
(
    [long] => Array
(
    [0] => 183153327
                [1] => 183153328
            )
    ))
```

it is realy like when we var_dumped but this is a string that api response to me,How can i access that two value 183153327 , 183153328.
Can i convert this string to an array  ??

that is not object is a string response and when I use

```
$result->SendSMSResult->long[0]
```

i have this error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($result);` and `var_dump($result->SendSMSResult);`?

Comment: this is result of `var_dump($result)`  :  `string(219) "stdClass Object ( [SendSMSResult] => stdClass Object ( [long] => Array ( [0] => 183153423 [1] => 183153424 ) ) ) "`

Comment: and when i `var_dump($result->SendSMSResult);`  :  I get this error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: If you don't have access to this API and change this result, you will need to use some regex to parse the result

Comment: I don't have access to API. how can i parse this response with regex ?

Comment: and the problem is the result could have more than 2 values

Comment: @تیمکبیروید Call those guys and tell them to remove **their** `var_dump()` and provide a proper response, either in `JSON` or `XML`.